# Malloc array of characters dynamic vs static C

Tags: c, char, malloc

So I'm basically trying to take an input of scanf of letters (no spacing between them), place each letter into an array and spit out the corresponding letter to the array by using dynamically allocated arrays (malloc).

Crashes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    char *userInput = malloc(sizeof(char)*3); /* dynamic */
    scanf("%s", &userInput);
    printf("user inputed %c", userInput[1]);
    free(userInput);

    return 0;
}
```

Runs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    char userInput [3];  /* array */
    scanf("%s", &userInput);
    printf("user inputed %c", userInput[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:
asd

Output:
s

My understanding of dynamically allocated arrays was that `char userInput [3];` is equivalent to `char *userInput = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);` but apparently from this case that isn't true? Anyone care to explain/help?

Comment: The problem is NOT with the array declaration.   Rather that problem is with the call to scanf() and its' format string.   Strongly suggest reading the man page for scanf().   As it is, both the posted code sets exhibit the same undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Coincidentally, the main problem with your code is that it is vulnerable to a stack overflow. `scanf` has no way of knowing how big `userInput` is, because you didn't tell it, and will happily continue filling memory long past the end of your very short array.

If you want to capture exactly three characters (with no nul terminator), use `scanf("%3c", userInput)` instead. Note that without the NUL, you must not expect to treat `userInput` as a string; printing it via `printf` for example will result in a random amount of gibberish owing to the fact that C does not know where the string ended.

Now, to answer your actual question on "what's the difference between malloc and the static array": the difference is of scope. If you only ever use `userInput` before its creating function `return`s, there is no practical difference, but you're in trouble the minute you try to do something like this:

```
int function1 {
     char my_string[3];

     scanf("%3c", my_string);

     return my_string; /* WRONG! DANGER! */
}
```

The `return` in the above example will happily return the pointer to `my_string` to the calling function. However, as soon as `function1` returns, the stack is rolled back and the memory `my_string` occupied is essentially gone (and likely already re-used). The results are unpredictable but almost universally very bad for your program.

However, had you used `malloc()` instead, you could safely return the `my_string` pointer and the memory would persist until someone later called `free(my_string)` (where `my_string` is the pointer to the original `my_string`; it need not be named the same!).

This highlights another difference: with a stack variable such as `char my_string[3];`, you do not need to worry about (and indeed cannot) `free()` the memory, where as if the memory is `malloc()`'d instead, you *must* `free()` it if you wish to reclaim the memory.

There are some nuances to the above, such as file-scoped variables and `static` function variables, which I leave as topics for further reading.

Comment: @M.M The `c` conversion specifier does not add a null character whereas the `s` conversion specifier does. For a buffer of size 3, `%3c` would be fine, assuming _exactly_ 3 characters are meant to be read, and a null character is not necessary. Otherwise, I'd say a buffer of size 3 should use `%2s`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in Giorgi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594942/1928852), the main problem is the incorrect usage of the *address-of* operator `&`.

---

However, the reason *why* it worked on one case and why it didn't work on another is *very interesting*.

1. `char array[3]`: When you declare that array, memory space will be allocated for it and `array` will be a label to that location(memory address). When you pass `array` to `scanf` (or use it anywhere else without subscripting `[]`), you're passing an *address* to that function. Because of that, when you use the `&` operator on the label `array`, **it returns the same address to you BUT with different type** (`T(*)[3]`), which your compiler *probably complained about*. But, as the memory address is valid, it worked as expected.
2. `char *array = malloc()`: When you declare that variable, memory is also reserve for it, but this time in a different place and the space reserved is `sizeof T(*)`, so it can hold a memory address. This variable also has an address in memory, which you can also get using `&array`. Then you `malloc` some memory and `malloc` returns to you an *address of a memory block* which you can now use. You can get that memory address by simply doing `array`. So, when you call `scanf` with the `&array` **you're passing the variable address instead of the block address**. That's why it crashes (I'm guessing you were not entering only two characters).

Check this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *array[3];
    char *ptr = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));

    printf ("array : %p\n", array);
    printf ("&array: %p\n\n", &array);
    printf ("ptr   : %p\n", ptr);
    printf ("&ptr  : %p\n", &ptr);

    scanf("%s", &ptr);

    printf ("ptr   : %p\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./draft
array : 0x7ffe2ad05ca0
&array: 0x7ffe2ad05ca0

ptr   : 0x19a4010
&ptr  : 0x7ffe2ad05c98
ABCD
ptr   : 0x44434241
```

`scanf` got the address of the **pointer**, so when it saves the value it reads from `stdin`, it overwrites the address we had from `malloc`! The memory block we had is now gone, memory is leaking... Now, this is bad because we're overwriting stuff on our stack, memory is leaking, and it will crash.

Observe the last output: the value of `ptr` (which previously was the address of an allocated block) is now 0x44434241 (`DCBA`, [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/))! *How nice is **that**?*

Comment: @M.M: because format specifier type doesn't match to what was passed in right?

Comment: @Giorgi In case 1, if we enter **more** bytes than `array_size` it's UB (out of bounds write). In case 2, if we write **more** bytes than the `architecture pointer size` (4 bytes on 32bit, 8 bytes on 64bit), it will be UB (out of bounds write again).

Comment: @EnzoFerber: it's UB before that, check comment by M.M (due to type mismatch)